# Can't delete registry key using VBS

Tags: windows, windows-7, vbscript

I am trying to delete a registry key. Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )  
Dim strDelete
strDelete = objShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\test\")
WScript.echo(strDelete)
objShell.RegDelete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\test\"
WScript.Quit
```

When I run this, I get this output:

> Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> test
>   N:\RogueDevelopment\test.vbs(23, 1) WshShell.RegDelete: Invalid root in registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\test\".

My registry key is located at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\test\" and it has a default value of "test". The value in the key is being read correctly, but the key cannot be deleted. I am running this script on Windows 7. Why is this happening?

Comment: UAC prevents you from deleting keys in HKLM.  Use HKCU instead.

Comment: Not booted into Windows partition right now, but I suspect that you shouldn't use the trailing backslash after the last "t" in test "test\".  That, and it's probably an admin permissioning problem as Neil suggests below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have permission to open `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\test\` for delete access. If you really need to modify keys under HKLM, you will need to elevate your process.